# Use varchar stored procedure parameter in If condition of xquery insert

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xquery

Is it possible to use a nvarchar type sproc variable in an xquery insert statement within the stored procedure?
What I mean is something like this, in which an element is inserted only if a child element with the sought for value is present:

```
DECLARE @profiles_xml xml
DECLARE @profile_id int
DECLARE @user_id nvarchar(50)
SET @profile_id = 20
SET @user_id ='BC4A18CA-AFB5-4268-BDA9-C990DAFE7783'
SET @profiles_xml = (SELECT profiles from tbl_applied_profiles WHERE profiles.value('(Profile/ID)[1]','int')= @profile_id)
SET @profiles_xml.modify('
insert
if(/Profile/User/ID="user_id")
then <Activity>activity_name5</Activity>
else()
as first
into (/Profile/User/Activities)[1]')
```

The xml which @profiles_xml contains looks like this:

```
<Profile>
  <ID>20</ID>
  <User>
    <ID>BC4A18CA-AFB5-4268-BDA9-C990DAFE7783</ID>
    <Name>somename</Name>
    <Activities>
      <Activity>activity_name2</Activity>
    </Activities>
  </User>
</Profile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `sql:variable("@user_id")`, i.e.

```
SET @profiles_xml.modify('
insert
if(/Profile/User/ID=sql:variable("@user_id"))
then <Activity>activity_name5</Activity>
else()
as first
into (/Profile/User/Activities)[1]');
select @profiles_xml;
```

Comment: That works for the if condition statement as you suggest:
`if(/Profile/User/ID=sql:variable("@user_id"))`
But what if I want to also use parameters for the values of elements inserted into xml? When I try:
`then <Activity><Name>sql:variable("@service_name")</Name></Activity>`
for the insert, it literally inserts that value and I see
`<Activity><Name>sql:variable("@service_name")</Name></Activity>`
in the resulting xml.